# select do not return anything/php - mysql

Tags: php, mysql

hi these is my SQL function:

```
function checkSecureCode($securcode){
    if($result = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM groups WHERE securcode=".$securcode."")){
        $return = '';
        while($r = $result->fetch_object()){
          return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

when I call checkSecureCode($securcode); no return anything (false or true)...why?

securcode filed is an 32 MD5 code for example: 76411abbe4783f293c102a1b842e4147

This is filed datatype: securcode:
`"securecode" =>"securecode varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL"`,

Note: this function works for other fileds (for example an int(10) field)

Comment: You're missing quotes around your string value. You also don't check for errors.

Comment: Try `securcode='.$securcode.'"))` because it's not a simple `int`

Comment: You guys should post it as an answer.

Comment: @JorgeCampos I'm afraid I'll probably end up opening a potential can of worms lol

Comment: a while loop that returns unconditionally? **WHY**. It'd be impossible for that loop to execute more than once, so why have a loop in the first place? If you're just interested in if a row matched or not, you should be checking `->num_rows`.

Comment: @Fred-ii- lol it's true!!! \o/

Comment: @JorgeCampos 9 times of out 10, it is a can of worms. I rather use those to get me some real fish! ;-)

Comment: You may want to increase `varchar(32)` to `varchar(33)` then. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything

Comment: @JorgeCampos [`See, I was right`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24872913/select-do-not-return-anything-php-mysql#comment38631325_24872913) - Edit: OP deleted the comment lol - Apparently OP's code works for another script. Comment box is so handy.

Answer (score 0):

Your secure code isn't so secure, ensure that it is numeric,

if it is a string rather than a number, include string quotes:

```
function checkSecureCode($securcode){
    if($result = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM groups WHERE securcode='".md5($securcode)."'")){
        $return = '';
        if($r = $result->fetch_object()){
          return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

more on escaping strings: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Edit: Also, check your if function rather than a while...

Edit again: if you're using MD5 to verify the string, ensure you are matching MD5 results on both ends, since you are using an md5 function, no need to escape it as the hash will be alphanumeric.

Comment: Thanks for your advice but This function (and my old function) works with an int(10) fields...but do not work with a varchar(32) ... no return anything

Comment: That is because int comparison in a query is "X = ".$var;
in a string it is "X = '".$var."'";